# ¿Como esta solucion con sort() ordena un array de strings?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy ordenando un array en orden alfabetico usando como referencia un nombre que es tipo string, encontre el siguiente ejemplo en MDN pero no logro entender la solución, voy a comentar la linea que no entiendo:

```
const nombres = [
  { name: "Ivan" },
  { name: "Ana" },
  { name: "Zendaya" },
];

function sortAlfabeticamente() {
                                             // que significa 1 y -1?
  return nombres.sort((a , b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1)
};
```

Como ven si la condicion es true o false, devuelve 1 o -1 respectivamente y no logro entender como estos valores sirven para ordenar un array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método sort compara la posición del valor [Unicode](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) de cada caracter, según la conversión a string de cada elemento. Cuando el resultado de la comparación es un valor negativo indica que el elemento *a* tiene un valor menor al elemento *b*, por eso el resultado de tu script es un array ordenado de forma ascendente.

La condición no es necesaria, puedes obtener el mismo resultado de la siguiente forma:

```
const nombres = [
  { name: "Ivan" },
  { name: "Ana" },
  { name: "Zendaya" },
];

nombres.sort((a , b) => a.name - b.name);
```

Comment: Gracias ahora lo entiendo mejor